# Chrome JavaScript developer console: Is it possible to call console.log() without a newline?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console, logging

I'd like to use console.log() to log messages *without* appending a new line after each call to console.log(). Is this possible?

Comment: Was one of the answers correct?

Comment: I think @minitech's answer is correct: it is not possible. The other answers provide interesting, if somewhat orthogonal depth to our understanding of console.log().

Comment: @DaveLand I believe it is [perfectly possible](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41817778/2788872) by maintaining your own display buffer, and syncing that display buffer to the actual console by a combination of `console.clear()` and, e.g. `console.log()`.

Comment: @JohnWeisz: Thanks, but wiping the entire console for every "inline" update is not a solution for about 99% of applications. Still, have an updoot.

Comment: @DaveLand Yeah, it's more like a hack -- and now that I looked around, I realized it has been proposed before. Either way, it can be useful at times.

Comment: @JohnWeisz Useful for monitoring an ongoing process, using the console as a progress bar, provided that no other useful info appears in the log :-).

Answer (score 56):

No, it's not possible. You'll have to keep a string and concatenate if you want it all in one line, or put your output elsewhere (say, another window).

Comment: Actually, it is possible, but maybe not for the use everyone has in mind.  In my case, I was just trying to print a question to get input from a command line terminal. See the answer to this question for the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26683734/how-can-i-take-console-input-from-a-user-in-node-js

Comment: @deltaray readline’s `question` is not `console.log`. The question is also about the browser console, not Node.js.

Comment: @minitech you can use spread operator to print in one line. see in example jsfiddle.net/imranqau5373/7m65at9L/2

Comment: @imrankhan: That’s not what the question was. The spread operator doesn’t add anything new here vs. passing multiple arguments/using `apply`.

Answer (score 51):

In NodeJS you can use process.stdout.write and you can add '\n' if you want.

`console.log(msg)` is equivalent to `process.stdout.write(msg + '\n')`.

Comment: NodeJS is **not** Chrome. This answer is irrelevant to the question *'can you console.log without a newline?'*.

Comment: I landed here looking for this, so it was good to add the solution. Others think the same.

Comment: It's really _not_ the same as you've said. `console.log` in NodeJS has [a _bunch_ of customization points](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#new-consoleoptions).

Answer (score 29):

**Yes, it's possible** (check out the demo below) -- by implementing your own virtual console on top of the native browser console, then syncing it to the real one.

This is much easier than it sounds:

1. maintain a display buffer (e.g. an array of strings representing one line each)
2. call `console.clear()` before writing to erase any previous contents
3. call `console.log()` (or warn, error, etc) to fill the console with the contents from your display buffer

Actually, I've been doing this for some time now. A short, rudimentary implementation of the idea would be something along the following lines, but still capable of **animating the console contents:**

```js
// =================================================
// Rudimentary implementation of a virtual console.
// =================================================

var virtualConsole = {
    lines: [],
    currentLine: 0,
    log: function (msg, appendToCurrentLine) {
        if (!appendToCurrentLine) virtualConsole.currentLine++;
      
        if (appendToCurrentLine && virtualConsole.lines[virtualConsole.currentLine]) {
            virtualConsole.lines[virtualConsole.currentLine] += msg;
        } else {
            virtualConsole.lines[virtualConsole.currentLine] = msg;
        }
        
        console.clear();
        
        virtualConsole.lines.forEach(function (line) {
            console.log(line);
        });
    },
    clear: function () {
        console.clear();
        virtualConsole.currentLine = 0;
    }
}

// =================================================
// Little demo to demonstrate how it looks.
// =================================================

// Write an initial console entry.
virtualConsole.log("Loading");

// Append to last line a few times.
var loadIndicatorInterval = setInterval(function () {
    virtualConsole.log(".", true); // <- Append.
}, 500);

// Write a new line.
setTimeout(function () {
    clearInterval(loadIndicatorInterval);
    virtualConsole.log("Finished."); // <- New line.
}, 8000);
```

It sure has its drawbacks when mixing with direct console interaction, and can definitely look ugly -- but it certainly has its valid uses, which you couldn't achieve without it.

Comment: This is the best answer here. You can even init with say max lines that keeps the log stack sufficiently short, so that you don't end up logging a huge set of data.

Answer (score 19):

You can put as many things in `arguments` as you'd like:

`console.log('hi','these','words','will','be','separated','by','spaces',window,document)`

You'll get all that output on one line with the object references inline and you can then drop down their inspectors from there.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: I think this answer is useful.

Comment: This is useful. Even though it doesn't answer the question, it does provide a solution to what most people would be looking for when they find this question.

Comment: The reason why any would like to print without new line is that the following output is not known. Or just imagine a "loader bar" using e.g. dots.

Comment: Using multiple arguments breaks console.log styling as you can only style within first argument.

Comment: This answer is indeed useful.

Answer (score 15):

The short answer is no.

***But***

If your use-case involves attempting to log perpetually changing data while avoiding console-bloat, then one way to achieve this (in certain browsers) would be to use `console.clear()` before each output.

```js
function writeSingleLine (msg) {

  console.clear();
  console.log(msg);

}

writeSingleLine('this');
setTimeout( function () { writeSingleLine('is'); }, 1000);
setTimeout( function () { writeSingleLine('a'); }, 2000);
setTimeout( function () { writeSingleLine('hack'); }, 3000);
```

Note that this would probably break any other logging functionality that was taking place within your application.

Disclaimer: I would class this as a hack.

Comment: Very much a hack, but clever. 

If you tracked what's already been logged to the console (say by maintaining some kind of virtual buffer), you could rebuild the buffer and append a new string every time you cleared.

Comment: Upvoted for actually answering the question! The answer is NO.

Answer (score 3):

collect your output in an array and then use join function with a preferred separator

```
function echo(name, num){
    var ar= [];
    for(var i =0;i<num;i++){
        ar.push(name);
    }
    console.log(ar.join(', '));
}

echo("apple",3)
```

check also [Array.prototype.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) for mode details

```
var elements = ['Fire', 'Wind', 'Rain'];

console.log(elements.join());
// expected output: Fire,Wind,Rain

console.log(elements.join(''));
// expected output: FireWindRain

console.log(elements.join('-'));
// expected output: Fire-Wind-Rain
```

Answer (score 3):

If your only purpose to stop printing on many lines, One way is to group the values if you don't want them to fill your complete console

**P.S.:-** See you browser console for output

```js
let arr = new Array(10).fill(0)


console.groupCollapsed('index')

arr.forEach((val,index) => {
  console.log(index)
})

console.groupEnd()
```

[**console.group**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/group)

[**console.groupCollapsed**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/groupCollapsed)

Answer (score 1):

Something about @shennan idea:

```js
function init(poolSize) {
      var pool = [];
      console._log = console.log;
      console.log = function log() {
        pool.push(arguments);
        while (pool.length > poolSize) pool.shift();
    
        draw();
      }
      console.toLast = function toLast() {
        while (pool.length > poolSize) pool.shift();
        var last = pool.pop() || [];
        for (var a = 0; a < arguments.length; a++) {
            last[last.length++] = arguments[a];
        }
        pool.push(last);
    
        draw();
      }
      function draw() {
        console.clear();
        for(var i = 0; i < pool.length; i++)
          console._log.apply(console, pool[i]);
      }
    }
    
    function restore() {
      console.log = console._log;
      delete console._log;
      delete console.toLast;
    }
    
    init(3);
    console.log(1);
    console.log(2);
    console.log(3);
    console.log(4);    // 1 will disappeared here
    console.toLast(5); // 5 will go to row with 4
    restore();
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution using buffered output. Works with *deno* and should work with *node.js*. (built for porting pascal console programs to javascript)

```
const write = (function(){
    let buffer = '';
    return function (text='\n') {
        buffer += text;
        let chunks = buffer.split('\n');
        buffer = chunks.pop();
        for (let chunk of chunks)
            {console.log(chunk);}
    }
})();

function writeln(text) { write(text + '\n'); }
```

To flush the buffer, you should call `write()` at the end of program.
If you mix this with `console.log` calls, you may get garbage output.

Answer (score 0):

if you want for example console log array elements without a newline you can do like this

```
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5];

Array.prototype.log = (sep='') => {
    let res = '';
    for(let j=0; j<this.lengthl j++){
        res += this[j];
        res += sep;
    }
    console.log(res);
}

// console loging

arr.log(sep=' '); // result is: 1 2 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Useful for debugging or learning what long chained maps are actually doing.

```
let myConsole = (function(){
    let the_log_buffer=[[]], the_count=0, the_single_line=false;
    const THE_CONSOLE=console, LINE_DIVIDER='  ~  ', ONE_LINE='ONE_LINE',     
          PARAMETER_SEPARATOR= ', ', NEW_LINE = Symbol();
          
    const start = (line_type='NOT_ONE_LINE') => {
        the_log_buffer=[[]];
        the_count=0;
        the_single_line = line_type == ONE_LINE;   
        console = myConsole;  
    }
    const stop = () =>  {
        isNewline();
        console = THE_CONSOLE; 
    };                          
    const isNewline = a_param => {
        if (the_single_line && a_param==NEW_LINE) return;
        const buffer_parts = the_log_buffer.map(one_set=> one_set.join(PARAMETER_SEPARATOR))
        const buffer_line = buffer_parts.join(LINE_DIVIDER);    
        if (the_single_line) {                           
          THE_CONSOLE.clear();
        }
        THE_CONSOLE.log( buffer_line ); 
        the_log_buffer = [[]];
        the_count=0;
    }
    const anObject = an_object => {            
        if (an_object instanceof Error){
            const error_props = [...Object.getOwnPropertyNames(an_object)];
            error_props.map( error_key => an_object['_' + error_key] = an_object[error_key] );
        }
        the_log_buffer[the_count].push(JSON.stringify(an_object));
    }
    const aScalar = a_scalar => {
        if (typeof a_scalar === 'string' && !isNaN(a_scalar)) {
            the_log_buffer[the_count].push("'" + a_scalar + "'");
        } else {
            the_log_buffer[the_count].push(a_scalar);
        }
    }
    const notNewline = a_param => typeof a_param === 'object' ? anObject(a_param):aScalar(a_param);
    const checkNewline = a_param => a_param == NEW_LINE ? isNewline(a_param) : notNewline(a_param);
    const log = (...parameters_list) => {   
        the_log_buffer[the_count]=[];
        parameters_list.map( checkNewline );
        if (the_single_line){
            isNewline(undefined);
        }else{
            const last_log = parameters_list.pop();
            if (last_log !== NEW_LINE){
                the_count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return Object.assign({}, console, {start, stop, log, ONE_LINE, NEW_LINE});
})();

function showConcatLog(){
    myConsole.stop();
    myConsole.start();
    console.log('a');
    console.log('bb');  
    console.dir({i:'not', j:'affected', k:'but not in step'})
    console.log('ccc');
    console.log([1,2,3,4,5,'6'], {x:8, y:'9'});
    console.log("dddd", 1, '2', 3, myConsole.NEW_LINE);
    console.log("z", myConsole.NEW_LINE, 8, '7');
    console.log(new Error("error test"));
    myConsole.stop();
}

myConsole.start(myConsole.ONE_LINE);
var stop_callback = 5;
function myCallback(){
    console.log(stop_callback, 'Date.now()', myConsole.NEW_LINE, Date.now());
    stop_callback--;
    if (stop_callback>0){
        window.setTimeout(myCallback, 1000);
    }else{
        showConcatLog();
    }
}       
window.setTimeout(myCallback, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Yes bro, it is possible.

You can use the `process.stdout.write()` method instead of `console.log()` to log messages without appending a new line after each call.

> Here is an example:

```js
process.stdout.write("Hello ");
process.stdout.write("world!");
```

This will output "Hello world!" on the same line.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a spread operator to display output in the single line. The new feature of javascript ES6. see below example

```
   for(let i = 1; i<=10; i++){
        let arrData = [];
        for(let j = 1; j<= 10; j++){
            arrData.push(j+"X"+i+"="+(j*i));
        }
        console.log(...arrData);
    }
```

That will print 1 to 10 table in single line.

Answer (score -3):

```
// Source code for printing 2d array
window.onload = function () {
    var A = [[1, 2], [3, 4]];
    Print(A);
}

function Print(A) {
    var rows = A.length;
    var cols = A[0].length;
    var line = "";
    for (var r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
        line = "";
        for (var c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
            line += A[r][c] + " ";
        }
        console.log(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: `A.forEach(row => console.log(row.join(' ')))`