# printing "###" in one line using loops for javascript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to print the output in the same line by using console.log in JavaScript?console.log always a new line. For example: " ****** " using loops?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chrome JavaScript developer console: Is it possible to call console.log() without a newline?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627646/chrome-javascript-developer-console-is-it-possible-to-call-console-log-withou)

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible to do that.

You can refer this thread: [Chrome JavaScript developer console: Is it possible to call console.log() without a newline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627646/chrome-javascript-developer-console-is-it-possible-to-call-console-log-withou)

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
var output = [];
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    output.push('#');
}
console.log(output.join(''));
```

I'm probably off-topic :-|

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid not. **You can't call multiple `console.log` and keep it print on the same line.** *Every single call of `console.log` won't append the previous line.*

If you want to use loop to print in the same line, this code below will not work at all.

```
for (var i=0; i<100; i++){
    // do something
    console.log('*'); // Always prints in a line.
}
```

If you want to use loop but retain the output in the same line with multiple calls of `console.log`. I'm afraid you cannot. **You will need to call it once if you want to keep the output on the same line.**

Please see the reference in @rahul's answer. That will definitely clarify you very clearly.