# draw a Triangle in numbers (javascript)

Tags: javascript

I wrote this method that draw a Triangle. For example if you call drawTriangle(5) you get the following output:
 [image]

this is my code :-

```
function drawTriangle(t){

for (let i=1; i <= t; i++)
{

    for (let j=1; j<=i; j++)
    {
        console.log(j+" ");
    }

    console.log("\n");
}

}
let t = 5 ;
drawTriangle(t);
```

and i get this output 
[image]

I can not make them in a line I don't Know where is the problem .

Comment: Assemble a row as a single string before logging it. Don't do the logging 1 character at a time.

Comment: I second assembling the row first, but I would add that assembling the triangle as rows separated with a newline (`\n`) would be more performant. Additionally, `console.log()` is meant as a debugging tool and shoule be used as such if possible, opting for the function to return the triangle as a string that you then log to the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

console.log() will print a new line every time, store each line in a variable and print it at the end of innerLoop

```js
function drawTriangle(t){

  for (let i=1; i <= t; i++)
  {
    let eachLine = ''

      for (let j=1; j<=i; j++)
      {
        eachLine += j + " "
      }
      eachLine = eachLine.trim();
      console.log(eachLine);
  }

}

let t = 5 ;
drawTriangle(t);
```

Comment: your are missing the line-break

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet Is it needed? console.log() will add it implicitely

Comment: I actually missread the question. If it's about just console logging.. right, you don't need it

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627646/chrome-javascript-developer-console-is-it-possible-to-call-console-log-withou). You can use string concatenation in your inner for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Well other answer has already specified what you missed in your code.

I am adding it in case you want to see a alternate solution

```js
let n = 1;
let op = ''

while(n<=5){
  op+=new Array(n).fill(0).map( (e,i) => i+1 ).join(' ') + '\n'
  n++
}

console.log(op)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with linear time complexity--just `console.log(draw(n))`, where `n` is an integer, to see the result:

```
function draw(n) {
  let triangle = '';
  let prev;
  for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    if (prev) {
      triangle += '\n';
      prev = prev + ' ' + i;
    } else {
      prev = i;
    }
    triangle += prev;
  }
  return triangle;
}
```