# what is the equivalent of Java's System.out.print() in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, deno

It seems `console.log()` is the equivalent of `System.out.println()`

How to print strings in the same line with multiple calls?

Like:

```
for (let i=0;i<2;i++){
  console.log(i);
}
```

but print in the same line.

Comment: `console.log("1","2")`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/log

Comment: @cmgchess I need to use function to print.  like `for (let i=0;i<2;i++){console.log(i);}`

Comment: `const args = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 2; ++i) { args.push(i);}
console.log(...args);`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627646/chrome-javascript-developer-console-is-it-possible-to-call-console-log-withou

Answer (score 0):

console.log is not the equivalent, it does other things toolike formatting objects.

You're looking for [process.stdout](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#processstdout):

- process.stdout.write

and

- process.stdout.writeln

Comment: Only works on node js environment

Comment: It's similar in Deno ( Deno.stdout instead of process.stdout )