# Printing Triangle star(*) pattern in javascript using Recursion

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, design-patterns

I have been trying to solve printing down left side star(*) pattern in Javascript using recursion, i think my logic is correct but my syntax and concept might be wrong

```
// * * * * *
// * * * *
// * * *
// * *
// *
```

This is my code solution so far

```
var triangle = function (row, col) {
    if(row == 0){
        return
    }
    if(col < row){
        console.log("*")
        triangle(row, col + 1)
    }else{
        console.log("\n")
        triangle(row - 1, 0)
    }
}
triangle(4, 0)
```

output

```
*
*
*
*


*
*
*


*
*


*
```

But i want the output to be

```
* * * * *
* * * *
* * *
* *
*
```

Comment: Evidently, [it is not possible to call console.log() without a newline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627646/chrome-javascript-developer-console-is-it-possible-to-call-console-log-withou). "You'll have to keep a string and concatenate if you want it all in one line..."

Answer (score 1):

`console.log()` closes the output stream automatically, the "line break" is because it is the next output session. You will see its true form if you use `document.write`.

```js
var triangle = function (row, col) {
    if(row == 0){
        return
    }
    if(col < row){
        document.write("*")
        triangle(row, col + 1)
    }else{
        document.write("<br/>")
        triangle(row - 1, 0)
    }
}
triangle(4, 0)
```

But if you insist to use `console.log()`, some modification must be made:

```js
var triangle = function (row, col, stream = '') {
    if(row == 0){
        return
    }
    if(col < row){
        stream += '*'
        triangle(row, col + 1, stream)
    }else{
        console.log(stream)
        stream = ''
        triangle(row - 1, 0, stream)
    }
}
triangle(4, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks man..... I think I would go with the second solution, the first solution return an error when run in VS code "ReferenceError: document is not defined" since i am not running it on HTML environment

Answer (score 0):

check this solution

```js
 function triangle(row){
        var print="";
        if(row==0){
            return;
        }
        for(var i=0;i<row;i++){
            print+="* "
        }
        console.log(print);
        triangle(row-1);
        
    }
    triangle(5);
```

Comment: Thanks man....I appreciate, this is cleaner but i think running it on for loop would increase it complexity(i might be wrong though)